# IntToHex of values in a 512 byte array relating to a CreateFile Handle always return the same output? FreePascal\Delphi syntax.

Tags: delphi, arrays, freepascal

Long story short, my program allows the hashing of things. The one thing it currently lacks is the ability to hash physical disks in Windows version (the Linux version allows the user to select /dev/sda etc).

I have created a button that, when clicked, lists the attached devices to give me "\.\PHYSICALDISKX" (thanks to suggestions from SO users in reply to my earlier posts). I can then pass that value to the Windows API function, CreateFile, when the user double clicks it, to create a handle to it as a ListBox double click event. So I've done all of that. Code below refers.

However, I want to check that the CreateFile handle that I've established is working - the if statement suggests that it is, but I need to check I can actually read data to pass to my other functions. To test that, I am trying to read in the first 512 bytes of any given disk and "quickyl" display it in a memo box. However, I can't for the life of me work out why my output is incorrect, which it is. I get some hex values, but they are not the same hex values that are present in the the first 512 bytes. And they are always the same list of hex values, regardless of what disk I look at! So I have no clue where these values are coming from or why theey are always the same. The whole idea is for me to check my handle is OK and that I can in fact read data from the disk for me to then pass to my hashing functions.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   listBox : TListBox;
   index   : Integer;
   hDiskToHash, i : integer;
   DiskHashValue, DiskToHashFileName, TmpStr : string;
   RawMBR : array [0..511] of byte;
   bytesread : DWORD;
 begin
   i := 0;
   // Cast the passed object to its correct type
   listBox := TListBox(Sender);

   // Get the index of the selected list item
   index   := listBox.ItemIndex;

   // Display the selected list item value
   ShowMessage(listBox.Items[index]);

   // sValue1 is a global variable containing string '\\.\PHYSICALDISKX', populated by procedure TForm1.GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo;
   hDiskToHash := Windows.CreateFile(PChar(sValue1), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
   if hDiskToHash <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
   begin
      SetFilePointer(hDiskToHash,512 * 0,nil,FILE_BEGIN); // replace 0 with sector that you wish to read
      ReadFile(hDiskToHash, RawMBR[0], SizeOf(RawMBR), bytesread, nil);
      for i := Low(RawMBR) to High(RawMBR) do
        begin
        Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToHex(RawMBR[i],2)); // Add each hex byte on a new line
        end;
      CloseHandle(hDiskToHash);
   end
   else
   begin
    ShowMessage('Failed to open '+sValue1);
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Try adding the FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES flag to the CreateFile, Also if you want to read the MBR you must al the DeviceIoControl function passing the `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` value

Comment: How do you know that the first 512 bytes of the disks *aren't* all the same? Also, since you're suspicious that something is wrong, why aren't you checking the API functions' return values? You're not checking whether ReadFile succeeded or how many bytes it actually read.

Comment: That bit is included in `GENERIC_READ`, @Rruz.

Comment: Rob - fair points! Like a fool, I didn't realise ReadFile returns a true or false boolean. I've added it as an if then and it's not executing so must be returning false. So my ReadFile isn't working, for one thing. As for how do I know they are not the same - I have another hex editor and I am looking at 3 different physcial disks and I can see they are have varying 512 bytes at sector 0.

Comment: Just noticed - FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS for CreateFile. The Windows API states FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS is for when access is intended to be random! Not the case for me. I will change that and see what happens!

Comment: Nope - still no joy. Have changed the CreateFile line as follows : hDiskToHash := Windows.CreateFile(PChar(sValue1), GENERIC_READ, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);   in accordance with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but ReadFile is still false. :-(  RRUZ - Comment 1 - is that true even if I want my program to read a full disk, from secto 0 to the very end in read only mode? If so, that might mess me up a bit! I don't know how I'll pass some sectors one way and other sectors another to my hashing routines.

Comment: I am not sure you get what means these flags. Look at [Raymond's post about](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/20/10258690.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: OK. You've determined that `ReadFile` returns zero. The next step is to call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong. The documentation says so. You'll get an error code. Find that number in [the tables in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx). Also, please remember to use the "@" symbol in front of our names so that we'll be notified when you reply to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Windows are you running on?  The [CreateFile() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) states:

> Direct access to the disk or to a volume is restricted. For more
>   information, see "Changes to the file system and to the storage stack
>   to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access in Windows
>   Vista and in Windows Server 2008" in the Help and Support Knowledge
>   Base at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448.

With that said, try this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  listBox : TListBox; 
  index   : Integer; 
  hDiskToHash: THandle;
  i : integer; 
  RawMBR : array [0..511] of Byte; 
  Offset, BytesRead : DWORD; 
begin 
  // Cast the passed object to its correct type 
  listBox := TListBox(Sender); 

  // Get the index of the selected list item 
  index := listBox.ItemIndex; 
  if index = -1 then Exit;

  // Display the selected list item value 
  ShowMessage(listBox.Items[index]); 

  // sValue1 is a global variable containing string '\\.\PHYSICALDISKX',
  // populated by procedure TForm1.GetWin32_DiskDriveInfo; 
  hDiskToHash := Windows.CreateFile(PChar(sValue1), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0); 
  if hDiskToHash = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Offset := 512 * 0; // replace 0 with sector that you wish to read 

    if (SetFilePointer(hDiskToHash, Offset, nil, FILE_BEGIN) <> Offset) then raise Exception.Create("Did not seek to sector 0 correctly!");

    if not ReadFile(hDiskToHash, RawMBR[0], SizeOf(RawMBR), BytesRead, nil) then RaiseLastOSError;
    if BytesRead <> SizeOf(RawMBR) then raise Exception.Create("Did not read the full MBR!");

    for i := 0 to BytesRead-1 do 
    begin 
      Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToHex(RawMBR[i], 2)); // Add each hex byte on a new line 
    end; 
  finally
    CloseHandle(hDiskToHash); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Writing too much C code lately, are we ?  != equals <> in pascal :)

Comment: My primary development language is C++, I don't do much Delphi work other than component writing.

Comment: Thank you very much RL. Your solution worked! I had to change a few bits and pieces and I would have worked out the minor syntax differences. I very much value the fact that you are able to switch between one lang and another. I wish I could master one lang, let alone use multiple ones!! Thanks again. Ted